# Vue and Webpack tree shaking, sideEffects and CSS: CSS of unused components being loaded

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

We are trying to figure out the correct way of handling tree shaking for CSS in Vue Single File Components with Webpack.

In package.json, I have: `"sideEffects": ["*.css", "*.less","*.vue" ]`, this seems to be working properly for stopping Vue components from loading when they shouldn't be. However, every single `<style>` tag from the SFCs is been loaded on the page.

How we are loading our SFC is from a NPM package that list a bunch of exports, like

```
export blah from 'blah.vue';
export blah2 from 'blah2.vue';
export blah3 from 'blah3.vue';
```

Even if in our JavaScript I have just `import { blah3 } from 'a-npm-package';` it is including the styles from all three. Since we have a quite a few Vue components this is leading to a lot of unused CSS being added to the page.

How can we prevent this? There has to be a better more dynamic way of handling styles rather than just dumping them all into the page even if only 1/10th of them is being used?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MiniCssExtractPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/) to tree shake CSS. Also if you're using scss or sass, you can add those loaders as well.

```
// webpack.config.js (production)
const path = require('path')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',

  entry: path.resolve('src/index.js'),

  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve('dist'),
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          // Extract the css to file
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          // Handle import of `.css` files in your app
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    // Extract all css into a separate file
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
    }),
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you use [lazy loading components?](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/lazy-loading-individual-vue-components-and-prefetching/)

The components with the `style` tag will be loaded only when it's needed.

You can do the same for routes with the [lazy loading routes.](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html)

Answer (score 0):

If components are only sometimes needed, then lazy-loading them is a good way to reduce clutter.

ex:

```
const MyComponent = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "MyComponent" */'../components/MyComponent');
```

https://vuedose.tips/dynamic-imports-in-vue-js-for-better-performance/

You could also incorporate plugins into your Webpack config to help manage bulky code, such as [MiniCSSExtractPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/), in this case.